# Substitute values based on condition and compare values from multiple files with AWK

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I've spent the day trying to figure this out but didn't succeed. I have two files like this:

File1:

```
chr id pos
14 ABC-00 123
13 AFC-00 345
5  AFG-99 988
```

File2:

```
index id chr
1 ABC-00 14
2 AFC-00 11
3 AFG-99 7
```

I wanna check if the value for chr in File 1 != from chr in File 2 for the same ID, if this is true I want to print some columns from both files to have an output like this one below.

Expected output file:

```
ID OLD_chr(File1) NEW_chr(File2)
AFC-00 13 11
AFG-99 5 7
.....

Total number of position changes: 2
```

I got one caveat though. In File 1 I have to substitute some values in the $1 column before comparing the files. Like this:

```
30 and 32 >> X
31 >> Y
33 >> MT
```

Because in File 2 that's how those values are coded. And then compare the two files. How in the hell can I achieve this?

I've tried to recode File 1:

```
awk '{ 

        if($1=30 || $1=32) gsub(/30|32/,"X",$1);
        if($1=31) gsub(/31/,"Y",$1);
        if($1=33) gsub(/33/,"MT",$1);
  
        print $0
  
    }'  File 1 > File 1 Recoded
```

And I was trying to match the columns and print the output with:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next} (a[$1] !=$3){print  $2, a[$1], $3 }' File 1 File 2  > output file
```

Comment: I think you want `$1==30` instead of `$1=30` (and same for other comparisons).  And ++ for sample data/required output/current output and ... code! Good luck.

Comment: Since you want to included conversion of 30 to X etc in the script you should have included some of those cases in your example ro demonstrate that requirement and so when we were testing we could verify that our script does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    map[30] = map[32] = "X"
    map[31] = "Y"
    map[33] = "MT"
    print "ID", "Old_chr("ARGV[1]")", "NEW_chr("ARGV[2]")"
}
NR==FNR {
    a[$2] = ($1 in map ? map[$1] : $1)
    next
}
a[$2] != $3 {
    print $2, a[$2], $3
    cnt++
}
END {
    print "Total number of position changes: " cnt+0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
ID Old_chr(file1) NEW_chr(file2)
AFC-00 13 11
AFG-99 5 7
Total number of position changes: 2
```

Comment: Scratched my head for a while until it snapped that `X`, `Y` and `MT` were just encodings to protect for, but not present in `file1` or `file2`...

Comment: Thank you Ed. I still got a long way to go to learn AWK. I'l get there! :D

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{                                         # executed at the BEGINning
        print "ID OLD_chr("ARGV[1]") NEW_chr("ARGV[2]")"
    }
    FNR==NR{                                       # this code block for File1
        if ($1 == 30 || $1 == 32) $1 = "X"
        if ($1 == 31)             $1 = "Y"
        if ($1 == 33)             $1 = "MT"
        a[$2]=$1
        next
    }
    {                                              # this for File2
        if (a[$2] != $3) {
            print $2, a[$2], $3
            count++
        }
    }
    END{                                           # executed at the END
        print "Total number of position changes: " count+0
    }
' File1 File2
```

```
ID OLD_chr(File1) NEW_chr(File2)
AFC-00 13 11
AFG-99 5 7
Total number of position changes: 2
```

Comment: Thank you Gilles, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.